# How do I change the value of multiple fields in a array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Recently I have been working on a Java program. Today I have ran into an issue, where I would have to use values of a range of fields in a array. The length of the array is unknown, it is basically user input broken down into pieces. When I say I want to use the values of multiple fields in an array I mean something like that example from Ruby I am going to give you:

```
puts arr[1..10]
```

I can't seem to find the Java version of that thing.

I searched on the internet for the solution but I think I wrote the question wrong because it all led me to a tutorial how to make arrays.

Comment: and what are you supposed to do with those values?

Comment: You are looking for `Arrays.copyOfRange`

Comment: @Stultuske I need to take them and put them into a single String.

Comment: iterate over them and apply String concatenation

Comment: @Jorn Thanks. I am going to try that right away.

Comment: Please include examples of input and expected output/product.  Please include your attempt and highlight where it you are struggling.  There is a germ of multiple questions here so it is unclear what part you actually need help with.  Clear and concise questions produce better answers faster.

Comment: @smoowe2125, so, that _Ruby_ code is saying, print out values 1 through 10 from _arr_?

Comment: I think that the OP is asking how to do [array slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) in Java.  The short answer is that you can't.  Java doesn't support it.

Comment: But you >can< do something similar to slicing with `List.sublist`.   And note that `Arrays.copyRangeOf`  is NOT equivalent to slicing because it is creating a new array.  Changing the copy doesn't change the original array.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a syntax for ranges, in *Java*.

You can utilize the *[Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))* method, to print an array.

And, as *@Jorn* mentioned, you can use *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int))* to isolate the values.

The upper-bound value is exclusive.  So, you'll need to use *11*.

```java
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, 11)));
```

Ouput

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```